# How to fetch data from API once, then use that data many times?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a function which makes a post request through JQuery's $.post() method and retrieves a list of customers from an API. I have to load this list of customers inside a dropdown list, for the user to select one. Then the user will have the possibility to add another dropdown list on the client, which has to be filled with the same data fetched previously from the API.

```
    function fillCustomerList(selector) {
    let req =
    {
        "api_uid": /*myapiuid*/,
        "api_key": /*myapikey*/
    };

    req = JSON.stringify(req);

    $.post("https://api.fattureincloud.it:443/v1/clienti/lista", req, "json")
        .done(function (data) {
            var customerList = data["lista_clienti"];

            //fill first product list with products
            for (let i = 0; i < customerList.length; i++) {
                $(selector+" .customerList").append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + customerList[i]["nome"] + "</li>");
            }
        }).fail(function () {
            //TODO show error message
            console.log("getCustomerList error");
        });

    var customerList = data["lista_clienti"];

    //fill first product list with products
    for (let i = 0; i < customerList.length; i++) {
        $(selector + " .customerList").append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + customerList[i]["nome"] + "</li>");
    }
}
```

What I've tried to do is to access the previously filled dropdown list and its content, just to copy it and then show an identical one.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var ncustomers = 0;//number of customers

    //Add first customer
    ncustomers++;
    AddCustomer(ncustomers);

    //filling list with data fetched from api
    fillCustomerList("#customer-1");

    /*Trying to get list content*/
    $("#customer-1 .customerList).html();//this is empty, since the request 
    //hasn't finished yet and filled the list
});
```

Since the request is asynchronous, by the time I try to access the list it's still empty.

The only solution that I found is to re-fetch the data from the API every time the user wants to generate a new dropdown list, which I don't think is good, given the fact that I have a limit to the number of API calls to the service.

Is there a way of doing this in which I only have to make the request **once**? Or do I have to retrieve the **same** data through many differed requests?

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Save your first Ajax call result into a variable. Then when another drop down created, use the saved result to generate the options for drop-down.

Comment: But the thing is that I can only safely (which means being sure that the variable is not empty) access the ajax call result inside the .done() callback, am I right? If so,  how can I return that result to the document.ready(), being able then to fill each new list with that data?

Comment: Yes but there's nothing stopping you saving the data to a variable readable *outside* the done callback.

Comment: @XPD @Utkanos Thanks!! I saved the data inside a global variable and then checked its value in an if statement `if(customerList) //do things`. Now everything's working just fine.

Comment: Beware global variables. It's generally best to keep your entire code within a namespace, i.e. an object that lives globally. So the key for you here is to access a variable that is declared higher up than the current, local scope - but not, itself, totally global.